# Difference between gmaps and normal cross domain ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, cross-domain

Why if I do an ajax call with the getJSON method to the address:
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=EXAMPLE" I do not get any error, but if I call an external domain (not google), the browser returns me the error: violation of the cross-domain policy?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header is set by Google to "*".  This means allow access from any domain.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

It is possible that other domains to which you are making similar requests are not doing this.  Or maybe they are restricting access:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com
```